# How to reference from another file?

Tags: spring-mybatis

- There are A mapper/B mapper files.
- A mapper has  .
- I want to reference **"CommonWhere" of A mapper file in B mapper.**

Is there a way?

I tried the formula below for reference in file B, but it did not work.

B mapper file
->

Comment: It should work. Here's an [example](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/2d5358ac421ad498757143c19cafa9f11beaf69c/src/test/resources/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/refid_resolution/ExternalMapper1.xml#L27).